# Parsing XML file Using Java (DOM parser)

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing, dom

Ok, so I have been able to kind of parse through this xml file. But I am unable to get to the section I want.

http://www.faroo.com/api?q=iphone&start=1&length=10&l=en&src=news&f=rss

This is the URL to the xml because it looks very ugly just pasted on here. I have gone through this xml and have copied it to a file. The part that I need is the "title" in the first "item". I have gone through with this code:

```
System.out.println(myDocument.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0).getTextContent());
```

And this just prints all of the contents of the first "item", like "title" and "link" and "description" but I do not want all of it, I only want "title" to be printed. I have having problems getting it to work exactly right, but I feel like I am close. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) on the org.w3c.dom package:

> This attribute returns the text content of this node and its descendants.

Your code is calling `getTextContent()` on the `item` tag. If you modify your code so that it retrieves the text from the `title` tag, it works correctly.

```
System.out.println(myDocument.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

Note that this relies on `title` being the first child tag in `item`. You may want to change this to a more order-independant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code that iterates through the whole rss and gets all the titles, links and descriptions. You can create an object that has title, link and description as attributes and use it as you please:

```
try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("api.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;      
                System.out.println("title : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("link : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope that helps.